# Ps command shows more than 200% load, on dualcore cpu

Tags: linux

I use `ps -aux | awk 'NR > 1 {sum += $3;} END {print sum;}'` on dualcore cpu.

But when i turning on a stress test, i sometimes have peak about 230-250% for few seconds. After it slowly get around 190-196%

What i do wrong ?

Comment: `What i do wrong ?` What do you mean? Did you do something "wrong"?

Comment: Why i got over a 200% on dualcore. If one core may be only 100% on it's max state. Correspondingly i must get 200% total cpu load, if stress test using all cores as it do. But i have this strange peak. How i can get properly displayed data ?

Comment: so did you do any research? Like https://www.google.com/search?q=top+more+than+100+cpu ? What have you found out? What exactly is unclear to you? `How i can get properly displayed data ?` What does "properly" means? Properly in what way? What is your processor? Do you have hyperthreading?

Comment: Sorry for my english. I sometimes cant explain my thoughts. I do not understand why i got over a 200 precentage. I know that fact, that mulicore cpus may show values over 100% (100 * core+threads count). But i have only 2 cores with no hyperthreading (celeron g1840). Why i got this strange values wtih this command ? And how i can get real cpu load without top ?